# Verify an AD users PrincipalContext on server-side connection

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory

To preface, I've got a client and a server program, and the client connects to the server over SSL.

I'm looking for a way to verify, with Active Directory, a `PrincipalContext` or `UserPrinicpal` that is passed to a server, over the SSL tunnel. This is to verify the identity of the client. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Or, does anyone know of a different/simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** If you want to authenticate user using LDAP, then it has already been answered here for how to [`"Validate a username and password against Active Directory?"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/290548/3482140).

From what I can understand from your question, you simply want to search if the user exists in AD.

On the basis of my assumption, I've given a similar answer here on [`C# PrincipalContext only changes password for some users, not all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635469/c-sharp-principalcontext-only-changes-password-for-some-users-not-all/48638347#48638347), but that is a step-ahead of what you require. The subset of that answer answers your queries.

Sample code:

```
     try
        {    // assuming _userID is the user-id to be checked in AD.
            PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.name", "DC=domain,DC=name", ContextOptions.SimpleBind, "bindUserID", "bindPassword");
            UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, _userID);
              if(null != oUserPrincipal){
              // user-id found and valid, continue further.
              // If you want to authenticate user, go as per NOTE section in my answer instead.
              }
             else{
              // return the message that the user-id could not be found.
              // preferably the user-id should be **SamAccountName**
              }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.ToString();
        }
```

**EDIT (Based on your comment):**

> ***`J. Doe`*** -> Despite the flack this might get me...It's going to be a broker
>   between a DMZ and clients on an internal network.

It seems you're looking for something like ADFS. [Read more about ADFS from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx).

Comment: I know that I can use that to check an identity, but I'm wanting to have the client pass me a `PrincipalContext` or `UserPrincipal` over the SSL connection, and then I verify with AD that they are who they say they are.

Comment: This looks like a AD authentication request from client to server problem! Wat sort of application are you developing? @J.Doe

Comment: Despite the flack this might get me...It's going to be a broker between a DMZ and clients on an internal network.

Comment: @J.Doe - It seems to me you're looking for something like ADFS. Read more about ADFS from here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx